# Stack Overflow login page broken in Safari

Tags: bug, status-completed, openid, safari

In Safari on a Mac, the login page for Stack Overflow is borked.

The salmon coloured "Why OpenID?" box is hovering over the login button.

Not the end of the world of course, but worth mentioning nonetheless.

Logout and [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login).

Comment: belongs on meta.

Comment: Am I the only one finding "broken" a bit strong ? There a visual glitch, which doesn't prevent using the page. Not good, needs to be fixed, ok. But far from "oh my, it's broken".

Comment: If this is in Snow Leopard I suspect it's duplicate. Can't replicate this in either Windows or Leopard.

Comment: @Diago: Can you tell us if you have `Trebuchet MS` installed in your Leopard?

Comment: Related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19052

Comment: Can replicate this on Safari 4, Leopard. But the boxes are not salmon-colored for me, they have no background.

Answer (score 1):

This happens on Linux too.

Its because the default sans-serif font on non-windows browsers are too wide.

May be set the width with `px`? (Oh the horror!)

Answer (score 0):

Broken for me also:

[broken in safari http://www.benlumley.co.uk/media/images/safari-so.png](http://www.benlumley.co.uk/media/images/safari-so.png)

Comment: Can you tell us if you have `Trebuchet MS` installed in your Mac?

Comment: i do indeed have it installed

Comment: @benlumley: mmm... that's strange... `Safari` should be using it... Does it happen on FF too? Can you check that `Safari` is using `Trebuchet` or, because of a small name change is defaulting to `Helvetica`?

Comment: Apparently still broken, though it wasn't until recently.  Very annoying.  Not sure how to check if Safari's using Trebuchet, though it is installed on the system

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Had to do with specifying `<input>` length="22" rather than style="width:300px".

Apparently length/size of an input field varies depending on the font, so it's a bad idea to set width that way -- always use a specific css size.