# The input field is too big when closing question as duplicate

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

This happens in Firefox 3.0.10 Ubuntu.

#### Screenshot:

http://img2.pict.com/12/e3/e4/1548211/0/800/q.png

Answer (score 3):

This most likely is related to a [few other css bugs on SOFU on non-windows platforms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19028/stack-overflow-login-page-broken-in-safari).

The most commonly noticed is on the login page.

Its because SOFU uses `ems` for the width of text fields, but the default font is `MS Trebuchet`, that most likely isn't available in your system, so the site falls back to `Helvetica` (hider than Trebuchet) or `BitStream Vera Serif`/`Deja Vu Serif` (even wider) or one of those.

This problem appears on both Linux/BSD and OS X.

Try installing the `liberation fonts` or [`msttcorefonts`](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/) (that has Trebuchet), or live with it for the time being, as it doesn't appear to be a concern for the dev team on the short term.

Answer (score 2):

This also happens in Safari (with the normal font size, so it's not my fault):

[image]

Answer (score -2):

It seems SO defines that input box as a fixed size rather than giving it a pixel width.

That works fine for IE on Windows with default DPI and font size settings. It also seems to work on Chrome. But Firefox seems to use a larger default font than IE. You can also change it which will affect it.